# C# unit test gone wrong

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2022

I have the following Unit Test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestValidatePanAndToken_IfPanDetailsIsNull()
{
    string pan = null;
    string token = "1234567890123456";
    _TokenPro = new TokenPro();
    _privateObject = new PrivateObject(_TokenPro);

    Exception testException = Assert.ThrowsException<TargetInvocationException>(() => _privateObject.Invoke("ValidatePT", pan, token));
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof(ExprException), testException.InnerException.GetType());
}
```

This method is in another unit:

```
private void ValidatePT(string pan, string token)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pan) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        throw new ExprException("Unable to convert token");
}
```

Now when it gets to the throw in VaildatePT, the test essentially quits, never going back to the Assert in the TestMethod. How do I fix this or is ther a better way to do it?
This test has been working for a long time, there have been no changes to the code above, and now it is just starting to fail, unsure why. Could it be that I'm running in Visual Studio 2022?
These tests were created in a much older version of VS.

Update, I see this in the Tests Output window:

````
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'ExprException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll
'testhost.net472.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: TestSourceHost: Enumerating source (C:\Code\Unit Tests\TokenPro.Test\bin\x64\Debug\TokenPro.Test.dll)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Resources.ResourceManager\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'testhost.net472.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: TestSourceHost: Enumerating source (C:\Code\Unit Tests\TokenPro.Test\bin\x64\Debug\TokenPro.Test.dll)): Loaded 'C:\Code\Unit Tests\TokenPro.Test\bin\x64\Debug\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll'. 
'testhost.net472.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: TestSourceHost: Enumerating source (C:\Code\Unit Tests\TokenPro.Test\bin\x64\Debug\TokenPro.Test.dll)): Loaded 'C:\Code\Unit Tests\TokenPro.Test\bin\x64\Debug\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.dll'. 
'testhost.net472.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: TestSourceHost: Enumerating source (C:\Code\Unit Tests\TokenPro.Test\bin\x64\Debug\TokenPro.Test.dll)): Loaded 'C:\Code\Unit Tests\TokenPro.Test\bin\x64\Debug\Microsoft.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.dll'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll```
````

Comment: depite the fact that unit-testing private members is a pretty akward thing which should be fixed as soon as possible, did you debug the issue and see where exactly the test continues after having thrown?

Comment: It doesn't go anywhere as the test is essentially done

Comment: however, see update...Unsure what file it's looking for to get the System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Comment: If I change to Assert.ThrowsException<ExprException>, it give me a null reference in the Assert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following will solve the issues you are seeing:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestValidatePanAndToken_IfPanDetailsIsNull()
{
    string pan = null;
    string token = "1234567890123456";
    _TokenPro = new TokenPro();
    _privateObject = new PrivateObject(_TokenPro);

    Exception testException = Assert.ThrowsException<ExprException>(() => _privateObject.Invoke("ValidatePT", pan, token));
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof(ExprException), testException.GetType());
}
```

The type parameter to `ThrowsException` should match the type you expect to be thrown, in your case `ExprException` and this is not a wrapped exception so you should be checking the type of the exception itself, not `innerException`.